# Method for "adding" new data to current open file C#

Tags: c#, openfiledialog, savefiledialog, binaryreader, binarywriter

I am writing a program where I have 2 listboxes with the same data but the one listbox items are update with the student name and their TOTAL score and the other with the student name and each individual judge score next to the student name. Everything is going good so far but now I am stuck... I have two methods Save() and SaveAs() where Save() automatically writes data to "FormData.bin" and SaveAs() lets the user enter their own file name.

Is it possible to re-write the Save() method so that when I click save it saves the current data to the file that is open like in MS Word when you are typing in document and just click save to add new typed data to current file. Here is my Save() method I wrote.

```
public void SaveEntry()
    {
        int itemsCount = Math.Min(lstbxStudents.Items.Count, lstbxStudentScore.Items.Count); 
        saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath;
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = "FormData.bin";

        {
            try
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create))
                using (BinaryWriter Save = new BinaryWriter(fs))
                {
                    Save.Write(cmbbxAge.Text);
                    Save.Write(cmbbxBelt.Text);
                    Save.Write(cmbbxCategorie.Text);
                    Save.Write(cmbbxGender.Text);
                    Save.Write(cmbbxGup.Text);
                    Save.Write(txtJudge1.Text);
                    Save.Write(txtJudge2.Text);
                    Save.Write(txtJudge3.Text);
                    Save.Write(txtJudge4.Text);
                    Save.Write(txtJudge5.Text);
                    Save.Write(txtOperator.Text);
                    Save.Write(txtPos1.Text);
                    Save.Write(txtPos2.Text);
                    Save.Write(txtPos3.Text);
                    Save.Write(txtPos4.Text);
                    Save.Write(txtPos5.Text);

                    for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++)
                    {
                        Save.Write(lstbxStudents.Items[i].ToString());
                        Save.Write(lstbxStudentScore.Items[i].ToString());
                    }

                    Save.Close();
                    fs.Close();


                }
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message, "CTSD Forms");
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance

Here is image of Form

[Window Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpbhJ.jpg)

Comment: Can you please clarify what you want to improve/have trouble with? Most of the programs (Word included) don't "update" existing files but rather completely overwrite with data loaded in memory all the time (Save/SaveAs). So "like Word" is not exactly clear explanation of problem.

Comment: Are you sure you want to save text to a binary file?   Getting it back out will be a problem.

Comment: If you want to _Save_, rather than _Save As_, you don't need a dialog. You keep the path of the file that you opened and give that as the first argument to `FileStream()`. All `SaveFileDialog` does is let the user specify a file path through a dialog.

Comment: Okay, for example when I choose the file name for example "FormTesting1.bin" and on other day I open the file everything is reloaded correctly as I wanted it but know I add some new data for example the students score from each judge I just want to overwrite the old data without having to go to the menu and clicking SaveAs() and then overwriting the same file name, instead I want the Save() method to automatically overwrite the old data with the same file name (FormTesting1.bin) whereas it currently overwrites the default filename I gave it in code saveFileDialog1.FileName = "FormData.bin";

Comment: @S.Rojak, I get an error stating the "Empty path name is not legal" - any ideas?

Comment: Are you saving the path from when you opened the file? Also, if you open Word, which is your behavior model, and close the document, then when you go to the File menu, _Save_ is disabled. When you have a new file, you either have to disable _Save_ or make it behave like _Save As_ until you have a file name.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you are trying to achieve is to append text rather than overwrite it. Take a look upon the [StreamWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx) class that also allows to specify if you want to [append the data or not](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx) when constructing the instance. It also allows to create/append to the file directly, without the need of a `Stream`.

Also, consider using proper names for variables:

`Save` is an action, not an object. `writer` would be better.

By using Write in the way you showed in your code, you will end with all the texts appended with no separators. You should consider using [WriteLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebb1kw70(v=vs.110).aspx) functions.

**[edit upon clarifications]**

`SaveEntry` should take a parameter to specify if save is done as `SaveAs` or `Save`. First save should always be a `SaveAs`. Also filename should be saved in the context (your form class, but it is better to have a "view model")

```
private String _currentFileName;

public void SaveEntry(bool saveAs)
{
   if (saveAs || String.IsNullOrEmpty(_currentFileName))
   {
        saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath;
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = "FormData.bin";
        var result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        // TODO: handle user cancellation
        _currentFileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
   }

   using (var writer = new StreamWriter(_currentFileName))
   {
       // TODO: do stuff with your writer
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't have the WriteLine function? Only (changed Save to writer) writer.Write();?

Comment: But everything is working fine as it is, all I want is the same kind of functionality as MS Words Save button